# How to show every elements of a recursive data type (Tree) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, binary-tree

I have this little problem where i need to write an instance of show that can print every element inside my recursive data of a tree :

```hs
-- | A binary tree representing a series-parallel graph
data SpTree a
    -- | Leaf node
    = LeafNode a
    -- | Series composition
    | SeriesNode a (SpTree a) (SpTree a)
    -- | Parallel composition
    | ParallelNode a (SpTree a) (SpTree a)

-- | An SP-tree can be shown
--
-- >>> show $ LeafNode 1
-- "Leaf 1"
-- >>> show $ SeriesNode 1 (LeafNode 2) (LeafNode 3)
-- "Ser 1 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)"
-- >>> show $ ParallelNode 1 (LeafNode 2) (LeafNode 3)
-- "Par 1 (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)"
instance Show a => Show (SpTree a) where
    show = ?
```

What is the best way to define this instance? Should I use pattern matching or guards?

I tried this for the leafNode but it gives me an error saying 
    `Data constructor not in scope: LeafNode :: Integer -> ()` when i try to run this line :`show $ LeafNode 1`

```
instance Show a => Show (SpTree a) where
    show (a)
        |  LeafNode a = show a :: Integer
```

Thank you !

Comment: Use pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still new at Haskell, but something like this could work?

```
module Main where

import           Data.List

data SpTree a
    -- | Leaf node
    = LeafNode a
    -- | Series composition
    | SeriesNode a (SpTree a) (SpTree a)
    -- | Parallel composition
    | ParallelNode a (SpTree a) (SpTree a)

parens :: String -> String
parens a = "(" ++ a ++ ")"

instance Show a => Show (SpTree a) where
  show (LeafNode x) = "Leaf " ++ show x
  show (SeriesNode x y z) =
    unwords ["Ser", show x, parens $ show y, parens $ show z]
  show (ParallelNode x y z) =
    unwords ["Par", show x, parens $ show y, parens $ show z]


main = do
  putStr $ show $ LeafNode 1
```